# Spring MVC not Jax RS complient : is it risky?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I read many posts on SO comparing Jersey and Spring MVC.
There is one point that seems interesting :
Jersey follows Jax RS standard while Spring MVC doesn't.

My question is : As I'm willing to deploy my Java app on a tomcat server, what's the risk to not following the Jax RS standard ? Are there performance issues ?

Regards.

Comment: Mind quoting your sources? I never had problems with Spring MVC.

Comment: Did you consider the opposite question: *What's the risk of following the Jax RS standard?*

Comment: @AdamArold I never said there would be problems with Spring MVC. I'm talking about not following the Jax RS standard?

Comment: @barton Why are you implicitly assuming there is no risk in using Jersey and the Jax RS standard, but there is a risk in using Spring MVC? What are you basing those assumptions on? Simply saying "Jersey follows Jax RS standard while Spring MVC doesn't" may be a statement of fact, but that in itself says nothing whatsoever about the risk level of either. So maybe I should ask you: Risk of what? Performance (since you mentioned that in your question)? Why are you assuming Jersey is faster than Spring?

Comment: @Andreas If I had answers I wouldn't ask those questions. I only try to get an answer. 
As I always tried to follow the Java APIs, I wonder why Spring didn't and how that design choice can have impacts while running on a J2EE container.

Comment: Then you should rephrase your question, because that's not what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Spring doesn't need to follow JAX-RS, as Spring has already had its own way of describing, injecting and exposing resources, before the standard was created. They could, probably, implement support for JAX-RS on top, but the benefits would be rather dubious as they have different expectations of the underlying system, and both can already be deployed equally well on either simple servlet containers or full-blown JEE servers. Moreover, the client of such an application couldn't care less if behind it is Spring or Jersey or anything else.

As someone has rightly commented, adopting JAX-RS isn't an advantage by itself. It's only so if the surrounding systems are JEE as well, e.g. if you're planning to use CDI ubiquitously.

If, on the other hand, you have Spring in the adjacent systems, you'd obviously go with Spring for the REST part as well.

If this REST app is the only thing, and no adjacent systems to integrate with exist, both choices are fine and there's no strong reason to favor one or the other. I'd still go with Spring as its ecosystem is way richer and evolves faster, but that's just my opinion.

JAX-RS has the advantage of being natively supported by the container, so the resulting app will be smaller as it needs less dependencies. This is a good thing in theory, but historically switching JEE servers has always been problematic due to differences in proprietary configurations (How do you define a data source?), provided library versions (Which JAX-RS implementation does the server give you? Which version? What if you coded against a newer version than what the server has?) and classloading strategies (if you package a newer lib version within your app, which one gets loaded first and when?). While Spring apps are bigger as they need to include Springs libs, they are much more resilient to the afore mentioned problems a you do everything *the Spring way*, so which server is underneath is much less interesting. It sounds silly, but the standard thing is often actually harder to port than the non-standard. This is of course just my own experience, and someone will chime in for sure with a different one.